# Test Framework in ROS2: state of practice as in 2020?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the state-of-practice of Test Framework in ROS2?  I guess they are using unit testing frameworks (like googletest) as in most open-source projects, as well as continuous integration tools like Jenkins. Are there ROS-specific stuff developed recent years that have already been adopted?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355352/test-framework-in-ros2:-state-of-practice-as-in-2020?/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2020-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's sections in the [Developer Guide](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Contributing/Developer-Guide/#testing) relating to this.

There's significant tooling and infrastructure to take advantage of existing open source testing tools and frameworks as well as linters. And yes there's significant CI visible on build.ros2.org and ci.ros2.org

if you'd like to know the state of practice I'd suggest browsing some of the core packages which all have significant testing.

- [rclcpp](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/tree/master/rclcpp/test)
- [rclpy](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/tree/master/rclpy/test)

You can also look at the [system_tests](https://github.com/ros2/system_tests) package for examples of integration tests.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2